# equations for slicing cone with planes

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Consider the cone formed by the revolution of $x=1$ and $y=1$ about $y=x$ for positive values. The vertex is at $(1,1)$ (in 2-space). Then slice the cone with a plane to generate a conic section.

> What are the equations for the conics?

I'm not sure because the lower half of this cone is now bounded in $(0,1).$ Slicing with the right plane should yield say a hyperbola like figure but with the two branches being small and large. The small branch is bounded in $(0,1).$

Thanks.

Comment: So we are rotating the line $(1,1,0) + t(0,0,1)$ around what exactly? Since $y=x$ defines a plane, I'm not sure how you are "rotating" a line around it.

Comment: y= x in the xy-plane is  a line, not a plane.

Comment: @user247327 I assumed we are in 3-space, since we are rotating to make a cone. Otherwise we have two lines $x=1$ and $y=1$, which are redundant to rotate around $y=x$. Indeed, we only plane slices making conics if we consider things in 3-space.

Comment: Yes, but to "get" to 3-space they rotate around a line in 2-space.  The two lines x= 1 and y= 1 rotate into each other, and sweep out a cone, when rotated about the line y= x, z= 0.

Comment: If you take the equations to be in 2D space and you rotate (ideally should be stated in 3D), one of the cones with vertex at $(0, 0, 0)$ and line of axis $x = y = z/0$ should be $z^2 = 2xy$.  Then you have the other cone with the same base and line of axis but vertex in opposite direction.

Comment: @MathLover yeah I'm trying to figure out how to state this in a more convenient coordinate system